# Building iOS UI properly with storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard

I'm a designer for a iOS app (very new to iOS development). Me and my partner are tasked with different parts of the app. Currently I'm trying to implement my designs via the storyboard. The design in question is this: https://www.figma.com/proto/LeFIuP3DClbqXnaZw9uZEk2X/AdPro-App-v1?node-id=32%3A1092&scaling=contain

Right now I'm thinking of using a stacked view > view > label + button for each block. Is this the proper way to do it? How would I also go about implementing the arrows too?

I appreciate any help you guys can offer!

Comment: That would work (there is no "proper" way -- lots of ways will work -- you should just try it).  If you want to support shorter phones (4/4s form-factor), you probably need a scroll view.  Arrows with images, probably.

Comment: While this question will likely be closed because it's very broad and "opinion based," your layout could be done with `UITableView`, `UICollectionView`, `UIScrollView` containing individual views and / or `UIStackView`, etc. Best bet is to just start working on it.